# @font-face not working on windows server?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, windows-server-2003, font-face

I developed a wordpress theme for a client on my test server which is running linux.  the @font-face loaded the .otf and rendered the text correctly in this instance.  It worked on multiple computers.

But now when I install this theme on a client's wordpress, running on windows server 2003, it doesn't load the font on any computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have narrowed this issue down to apparently an open type font vulnerability with windows 2003 servers.  the font in question was an .otf font.  when I tried a .ttf everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS in not sending the .otf with a proper MIME type set, that is why it is not working. You need to configure IIS MIME types to respond to .otf files as "font/opentype".

Comment: this was it! Thanks. Had to add mime type to server and website via iss manager as outlined here http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, windows server will allow this:

Put this in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Thumb this up!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Windows 2003, updated the MIME type as suggested by Maxim V. Pavlov, recycled the App Pool in IIS and all works fine...