# What do numbers next to font resources in Chrome Developer Tools mean?

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

[image: Red numbers]

What do the numbers mean?

The reason for asking is that the fonts are not rendering correctly using the following CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'letter';
    src: url('../fonts/letter-bold.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: bold;
}

.title {
    font-size: 22pt;
    font-family: letter,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Not the question here, but you could answer in a comment - is `'../fonts/'` correct for `@font-face` to load from a path relative to the css file?

Comment: The color red implies an error. Do you get information on hover/click?

Comment: If the `font` directory in the root? If yes, try `url('/fonts/letter-bold.otf')`

Answer (score 0):

It means that there was an error.  In Firefox/Firebug, there is no resources tab, but in the network tab it will show **304 Error not found** for the same font files.

And the fonts were not downloadable due to MIME settings. [@font-face not working on windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141920/font-face-not-working-on-windows-server)

The correct MIME type is provided in this SO answer: [Proper MIME type for fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907377/573261)

Comment: 304 header means 'Not modified' - meaning that a local cached version can be loaded from browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Can Chrome render OTF font files? I believe Chrome uses the .woff font type for font embed. If you don't have a woff file type use font squirrel to generate new font sources. EOT is for IE, Woff is for Safari/Chrome, it will also output TTF and SVG for you.

I think that will fix the issue.

Here is a link to the generator: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: FYI - .otf works in IE9(on Win7), IE10, also Chrome v22+(?). I was surprised at IE9 support.